# Draw syntax diagram with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I am trying to create these:

[image]

I have tried to make the first figure with this code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata,positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (first) [circle,draw,inner sep=1pt] {};
\node (second) [right=of first] {};
\node (third) [right=of second] {term};
\node (fourth) [right=of third] {};
\node (fifth) [circle,draw,inner sep=1pt,right=of fourth] {};

\node (sixth) [below=of fourth] {};
\node (seventh) [below=of third] {$+$};
\node (eigth) [below=of second] {};

\draw[->] (first) -- (second);
\draw[->] (second) -- (third);
\draw[->] (third) -- (fourth);
\draw[->] (fourth) -- (fifth);

\draw[->] (fourth) -- (sixth);
\draw[->] (sixth) -- (seventh);
\draw[->] (seventh) -- (eigth);
\draw[->] (eigth) -- (second);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which yields

[image]

what can I do to make it more pretty with no spacing between the non-labeled nodes (I have tried make them coordinates instead of empty nodes, but it didn't work properly with `\coordinate (...) [right=of ...];`).

I have also tried bending the arrows without luck. Should it be `\draw (A) -- edge[bend right] (B);`?

Comment: `\draw (A) edge[bend right] (B);` or `\draw (A) to[bend right] (B);` or `\draw (A) to[out=angle,in=angle] (B);`

Comment: Can you please expand the code snippet that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). It is much easier to help you fi you give us compliable code to start from.

Comment: Sure. I have updated expanded my code now :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the graphs library is a good starting point with many examples in the [manual](http://www.texample.net/media/pgf/builds/pgfmanualCVS2012-11-04.pdf):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,positioning,arrows}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
node distance=5mm,
>=stealth',
black!50,
text=black,
graphs/every graph/.style={edges=rounded corners},
skip loop/.style={to path={-- ++(0,#1) -| (\tikztotarget)}},
hv path/.style={to path={-| (\tikztotarget)}},
vh path/.style={to path={|- (\tikztotarget)}},
box/.style={%
    rectangle,
    minimum size=6mm,
    draw=black,
    top color=white, 
    bottom color=red!50!black!20, 
},
rounded/.style={%
    rectangle,minimum size=6mm,rounded corners=3mm,
    draw=black!50,
    top color=white,bottom color=black!20,
},
start/.style={%
    circle,inner sep=2pt,minimum size=2pt,fill=white,draw=black!50,
},
end/.style={%
    start,
},
]

\node[start] (start) {};
\node[right=of start] (p1) {};
\node[box,right=of p1] (term) {term};
\node[rounded,below=of term] (plus)  {+};
\node[right=of term] (p2) {};
\node[end,right=of p2] (end) {};

\graph [use existing nodes] {
    start -> term -> end;
    (plus) ->[hv path] (p1);
    (p2) ->[vh path] (plus);
};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Edit: This is more similar to your example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,positioning,arrows,calc}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
node distance=5mm,
>=stealth',
black!50,
text=black,
graphs/every graph/.style={edges=rounded corners},
vloop/.style={to path={-- ++(#1,0) |- (\tikztotarget)}},
hloop/.style={to path={-- ++($(0,0)-(#1,0)$) |- (\tikztotarget)}},
hv path/.style={to path={-| (\tikztotarget)}},
vh path/.style={to path={|- (\tikztotarget)}},
box/.style={%
    rectangle,
    minimum size=6mm,
    draw=black,
    top color=white, % a shading that is white at the top...
    bottom color=red!50!black!20, % and something else at the bottom
    % Font
    %font=\itshape
},
rounded/.style={%
    rectangle,minimum size=6mm,rounded corners=3mm,
    draw=black!50,
    top color=white,bottom color=black!20,
},
start/.style={%
    circle,inner sep=1pt,minimum size=1pt,fill=white,draw=black!50,
},
end/.style={%
    start,
},
junction/.style={circle,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=0pt},
]

\node[start] (start) {};
\node[junction,right=of start] (p1) {};
\node[box,right=of p1] (term) {term};
\node[rounded,below=of term] (plus)  {+};
\node[junction,right=of term] (p2) {};
\node[end,right=of p2] (end) {};

\graph [use existing nodes] {
start -> p1 -> term -> p2 -> end;
(plus) ->[hloop] term;
(term) ->[vloop] plus;
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you use `\coordinate` rather than `\node` for the joining points, you can avoid the spaces.